# How to hide specific sentence on page load with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to hide a specific sentence **"The leader of tomorrow, are great"** from the content below without calling any class or div.

Example:

```
<p>The leader of tomorrow, are great leaders</p>
<br>
The leader of tomorrow, are great leaders of tomorrow.
```

Any solution to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the content always in a paragraph element?

Comment: @Julius what about " leaders" and " leaders of tomorrow."? Should the whole paragraph be hidden or really only the specific part?

Comment: @NawedKhan The content are not always in paragraph, sometimes it's a standalone content.

Comment: @Axel Only the specific sentence. 'The leader of tomorrow, are great'

Comment: So my solution should definitely work for you @Julius... You should narrow the selector 'body' to the closest parent element as well

Comment: @Julius I added some more explanations to my answer - that actually works the way you are asking for - so what else :) try it and let me know if it isn't so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why does `jQuery('*:contains("sentence to hide")')` not work on this scenario?

It will match all elements that contain the sentence. So it will match the closest node but in addition **all parent nodes** all the way up. So instead of matching element eg in this case the "P-node" it will also match for body, html and even the script itself if it is inline because it also contains the sentence! And if the element that actual contains the sentence to hide is wrapped by lets say:

```
<div id="_1">
    <div id="_2">
        <div id="_3">
            <p id="_4">sentence to hide</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then with `jQuery('*:contains("sentence to hide")')` you will get a jQuery collection with 
*[{html}, {body}, {#_1}, {#_2}, {#_3}, {#_4}]*

---

### Here is another approach...

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').html(function(iIndex, sHtml) {
      return sHtml.replace(/The leader of tomorrow, are great/g, '');
    });
});
```

Or to have more control you can wrap the sentence and style the wrapper as you like...

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
    var sNeedle = 'The leader of tomorrow, are great';
    jQuery('body').html(function(iIndex, sHtml) {
      return sHtml.replace(
        new RegExp(sNeedle, 'g'),
        '<span class="hide-specific-sentence">' + sNeedle + '</span>'
      );
    });
});
```

and then in your CSS:

```
.hide-specific-sentence{
  display: none;
}
```

**NOTES:**

- I would not recommend to treat web content like this but if you have to for whatever reason you can do it this way
- narrow the selcetor to the closest possible parent that actual contains the sentence(s) maybe ".content" or whatever
- make shure that you do this action before anything else because
  attached event handlers could get lost (depending on the way they are bound)

*If you try the code as SO snippet you will get an error.* This is propably due to some internal restrictions (I guess). But I tried it local and it **works like a charme** or you can try with this [working PEN](https://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/gxQLxa?editors=0010) that also works like a charme...

Comment: So far, your solution seem to be the closest work around.
The issue however is that, when a word has an hyperlink in the sentence, it doesn't pick it up and doesn't work.
E.G The leader of [tomorrow](http://example.com), are great.

With the sample, it only work for "The leader of" and won't work if i indicate the complete sentence.

Comment: @Julius you did not ask for this. As you can See my solution uses regex. So just customize the regex. IMHO that would be another question!

Comment: Just as an update for anyone who might need it. I was able to remove the link with a wildcard selector before removing the remaining sentence. The code `$('body a[href*="http://www.example.com"]').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has the `contains`-method. Here's a snippet for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var result = $('*:contains("The leader of tomorrow, are great")');
});
</script>
```

The selector above selects any element that contains the target string. The result will be a jQuery object that contains any matched element. See the API information at: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text

One thing to note with the `'*'` wildcard is that you'll get all elements, including your html and body elements, which you probably don't want. That's why most of the examples at jQuery and other places use `$('p:contains("The leader of tomorrow, are great")')`

Comment: The problem with the contains() selector is that it hides all the element that has that sentence not just the specific sentence.

`$(function() {
    var foundin = $('*:contains("The leader of tomorrow, are great")').hide();
});`

Comment: @Julius This is not the only problem with `$('*:contains("sentence to hide")')`. Please see the edit on my answer that works exactly the way you are asking for!